# Is there a way to completely disable Dock?

Tags: macos, dock, launchbar

I want the Dock completely gone.  I haven't used it in the past three releases of OS X (10.5 to present).  I want it completely gone, and LaunchBar there instead.  Is there a way to kill the Dock so that it does not load or run?

Comment: I realise this was a while ago, but your comment to the original answer below indicates that you gave up on this idea. Have you tried the other solutions in the mean time? That 1000 second thing is amazing. I use my launchpad accessed via a touch pad gesture, which I much prefer to using the dock. Maybe you could update your original post with a summary of how things have moved on since the original question was asked.

Comment: No, I never tried the other solutions as none of them would have done everything I was looking for. I just think that given all the other more precise methods of interacting with Finder, the dock is antiquated. I didn't want to spend resources on it.

Comment: I agree about the dock and now use my mac without it. It's still there of course and you can still see it in app exposé but my screen real estate is now completely free of it. What is it that still troubles you about using Joonas' solution?

Comment: Favourited. Both for how to do this again and how to re-enable it later...

Comment: A simple psychological solution that works for me - move the dock to the right side of the screen. I have basically forgotten it's existence now

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The Dock process on OS X is responsible for more than just the actual Dock on your screen. It does a bunch of background stuff, including Dashboard. Most notably, the Finder won't function properly if the Dock process isn't running, so turning it off completely is pretty much a no-go without breaking OS X in the process.

The best I can suggest is keeping the dock hidden, and make the size as small as possible so you're less likely to trigger it.

You can also position it where it's least likely to get in the way - as you probably know, you can put it on the left, right or bottom of your screen. But you can also pin it to a particular corner, just use the `defaults write com.apple.dock pinning -string start` command. Type that command in Terminal (replace `start` with `end` to change which corner it goes in, or `middle` to go back to the default), then `killall Dock` to restart the Dock and apply the change.

Comment: Though this may have worked at one time, it doesn't seem to any longer. The only options that work currently it seems are left, right, and bottom as seen [here](https://macos-defaults.com/dock/orientation.html#set-to-left). If anybody finds a way to make this work, please update.

Answer (score 113):

[This article](http://www.lifehacker.com.au/2012/09/how-to-disable-the-dock-in-mountain-lion/) from Lifehacker.com.au suggests setting the Dock autohide delay to 1000 seconds, like so:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock autohide-delay -float 1000; killall Dock
```

To restore the default behavior:

```
defaults delete com.apple.dock autohide-delay; killall Dock
```

The author says he sets the delay to two seconds, so he can still get to the Dock in those rare cases when it's needed.

Comment: Instead of setting a small delay to get your dock back when needed, simply unhide the dock with command-option-D. This basically gives you full control on when you want to see your dock.

Comment: Perfect. I want the Dock to only appear when I do the "4 fingers up" gesture. And this suits me perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Setting to ~15 instead of 1000 works for me - if something happened to the keyboard I'd want to be able to get to the dock still in an extreme case.

Comment: Works on Ventura as well.

Comment: I'm on `13.5.2`. This makes the dock stop showing for a few minutes, but then reverts to normal behavior.

Answer (score 33):

This answer doesn't really add that much to what is already here, but I felt that the answers offering solutions for hiding it lacked some information.

I personally use [uBar](https://brawersoftware.com/products/ubar) and I've used the following set of terminal commands without any issues. I can only confirm that I've used these without any issues since El Capitan. I can't remember further than that for sure.

To be clear, this only hides Dock, so that you will never have to deal with it accidentally popping up.

For those who don't know, these lines of code should be run in Terminal. It can be found here: `/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app`. Just open Terminal and paste in the lines and press enter.

```
# Hide Dock
defaults write com.apple.dock autohide -bool true && killall Dock
defaults write com.apple.dock autohide-delay -float 1000 && killall Dock
defaults write com.apple.dock no-bouncing -bool TRUE && killall Dock

# Restore Dock
defaults write com.apple.dock autohide -bool false && killall Dock
defaults delete com.apple.dock autohide-delay && killall Dock
defaults write com.apple.dock no-bouncing -bool FALSE && killall Dock
```

> You can run each line separately as well.

Explanation on what each line does:

1. First line turns on autohide

   - As someone mentioned, `Cmd+Alt+D` still toggles Dock visibility just like before. This is useful if you need to assign application to a specific space. Using the Dock is the only way <sup><sub>(AFAIK)</sub></sup>.
2. By default when Dock autohide is on, hovering over the edge where it sits shows the Dock pretty much immediately. This line Makes the hover delay 1000 seconds, making it pretty much impossible to accidentally show dock if you happen to hover over the edge. You'd have to let it sit there for ~17 minutes.
3. This removes the bounce animation that happens when applications want your attention or when an application is launching. I've noticed that depending on the Dock icon size, they may peak from the edge when they start bouncing. This gets rid of that issue.

`killall Dock` at the end of each line forces Dock to quit and then it restores itself automatically. This is to basically load the new settings. It's only necessary to run `killall Dock` after the very last line, but this way it's easier to run the lines separately if necessary ...and in bulk it really makes no difference.

Comment: I'm on 12.6, and the autohide delay does not seem to take effect. If I set it to 1000 and kill Dock, it still appears almost instantly if I accidentally move the mouse over it.

Comment: @rcorre, Hmmn... Maybe try restarting the computer afterwards. It should work... I've been using this exact code snipped since like Mavericks on every major version up to Monterey, where it works just fine. I do maybe have some recollection if not always sticking but I can't remember the details of how it resolved. Maybe I ran the commands one by one or without killalle or tried different values first to see if anything sticks. Or perhaps it was the restart...

Comment: Unfortunately I tried restarting after, and the setting still doesn't stick. The dock appears immediately after moving my mouse to the bottom of the screen.

Comment: @rcorre, I found [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/rjrlsy/defaults_write_comappledock_autohidedelay_doesnt/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3): `defaults write com.apple.Dock autohide-delay -float 0 && killall cfprefsd && killall Dock` — Though oddly enough I have to say changing the delay between 0 and 1000 didn't seem to work with `killall cfprefsd`, which is supposed to clear preference cache, yet it works just fine when I leave it out. I don't know if it would be better to run `killall cfprefsd` by itself before or after trying to edit the autohide delay.

Comment: You can also run `defaults read com.apple.dock autohide-delay` so see the current delay, which I would imagine isn't what you're trying to set, if it isn't working.

Comment: `defaults read com.apple.dock autohide-delay` reports `1000` unfortunately. The dock still appears immediately if I move my mouse in the wrongplace.

Comment: Oh, sorry @Joonas! I missed the `killall cfprefsd` bit. That totally worked, thanks!

Comment: Works on Ventura as well.

Comment: Back again, over the years. This is the way peeps.

Answer (score 7):

You can change icons size to 1px using:

`defaults write com.apple.dock tilesize -float 1; killall Dock`

To restore it to usable size:

`defaults write com.apple.dock tilesize -float 64; killall Dock`

Or simply open **System Preferences** and change the Dock size there.

There's a downside though, you can't quickly inspect the Dock if you need to, without changing the size back.

Comment: It would help if you gave more information about this setting and how to set it back to its default.

Comment: This setting change the apple dock icon size.

Comment: to get back, run this command but replace 1 by 64

Comment: or simply go to system preference > dock and change size value

Comment: The down side of this idea is that it is not straightforward if you want to take a quick look at the dock.

Comment: Yes, as asked by @everett

Comment: I tried this and the dock is still there like a tiny little glitch at the bottom of the screen and app names pop up every time your mouse goes near it.

Comment: yes, you can't hide it completely with this technique. however, you can disable zoom on mouseover in settings

Comment: I already have magnification turned off, if that's what you mean by zoom. I'm pretty sure you can't stop the application names popping up with mouseover.

Comment: It's of course a hack, apple should implement a better way to disable dock

Comment: Joonas' solution above is better than a hack. I use that method and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

To double click an icon and toggle the behaviour. **using @Jonas code** -*Thanks!*

I saved the following into a file named `Toggle_Dock` then ran `sudo chmod +x Toggle_Dock` which might have not been needed. Now I can just use the icon to toggle the dock.

```
# Check if dock is hidden
if [[ "$(defaults read com.apple.dock autohide)" -eq "1" ]]; then
  # Restore Dock
  defaults write com.apple.dock autohide -bool false && killall Dock
  defaults delete com.apple.dock autohide-delay && killall Dock
  defaults write com.apple.dock no-bouncing -bool FALSE && killall Dock
  exit
fi
# Hide Dock
defaults write com.apple.dock autohide -bool true && killall Dock
defaults write com.apple.dock autohide-delay -float 1000 && killall Dock
defaults write com.apple.dock no-bouncing -bool TRUE && killall Dock
```

Answer (score 0):

The free app [Onyx](https://www.titanium-software.fr/en/onyx.html) has the option to "hide the dock" completely under the parameters tab. And with Xmenu (free) my dock is now a dropdown list.