# How to fix macOS Big Sur Dock after having customised it on Catalina for uBar

Tags: macos, dock

I had a sweet setup for using uBar for favourites and the MacOS Dock for seeing open applications before I upgraded to Big Sur.

I had used commands from this Ask Different question: [Is there a way to completely disable Dock?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/59556/is-there-a-way-to-completely-disable-dock)

Even after I upgraded to Big Sur, everything for working fine perfectly. I toggled some Dock settings in System Preferences and now I'm unable to get the auto-hide working. It is inconsistent now. It doesn't always auto-hide and gets in the way of other windows by covering
them.

1. I only want to access the Dock using Cmd+Opt+D
2. I know the Dock will show up in the Launchpad and ^+Up and that is fine.

How do I fix this?
I tried commands from the same question for restoring dock as well, and restarted the MacBook Air multiple times.

Please help.

Answer (score 4):

I executed commands from [this HowToGeek article](https://www.howtogeek.com/363857/how-to-fix-your-mac%E2%80%99s-dock-when-it-gets-stuck) to reset the Dock and restarted the Mac; which didn't help (yet). I had used both the commands - "The Simple Fix" `killall Dock` and "The Slightly Less Simple Fix" `defaults delete com.apple.dock; killall Dock`.

Then I relaunched the Finder as recommended in the same article and now I'm back to my fantasy setup.

Sorry for the bother, I hope this helps others as well. I had to set preferences for dock again. On Big Sur we no longer need to follow the Terminal commands from the Ask Different question mentioned above.

Comment: I had an issue of the Dock annoyingly covering the bottom of the Terminal window. It happened a few days after updating to Big Sur. Just running `killall Dock` once fixed it. Thanks for your answer!